# How do I automatically update the source of an image, based on a changing slider value and a checkbox id?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript/html so sorry in advance if the question isn't super clear.

I currently have an html file, where I want to display an image, once a button is clicked. This works, if I just set the path and it doesn't change. What I want to do now is to use the value of a slider and the id of a checkbox, once it's checked in my filepath. So once the slider value changes and the checkbox is checked, I press the button that changes the source of my image and the image is updated.

This is what I currently have for the slider and the checkbox:

```
<body>
<div class="slidercontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" class="slider" id="sl">
  <p>Epsilon: <span id="sl_demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>

var slider = document.getElementById("sl");
var output = document.getElementById("sl_demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var path ="img_"+String(checkbox_id_once_checkbox_clicked)+"_"+String(document.getElementById("sl").value)+".png";

  function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
<label for="l2-norm">L2-Norm:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" onclick="myFunction()"><br>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick= img.src=path type="button">
    Visualize Results</button>

<img id="img">
</body>
```

I had a solution before where I was accessing the changing slider value (`this.value`) within the `slider.oninput` function but this didn't seem like the ideal solution especially if I want to pass other values from other sliders to the filepath as well.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code but there is one irregularity in it; you need to give an element the id `text` so you won't get a error for it

```html
<body>
<div class="slidercontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" class="slider" id="sl">
  <p>Epsilon: <span id="sl_demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var checkbox_id_once_checkbox_clicked
var slider = document.getElementById("sl");
var output = document.getElementById("sl_demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var path = "img_" + checkbox_id_once_checkbox_clicked + "_" + document.getElementById("sl").value + ".png";

function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    checkbox_id_once_checkbox_clicked = "mycheckbox"
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    checkbox_id_once_checkbox_clicked = ""
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function changeImg() {
  document.getElementById('img').src = path
}

</script>
<label id="l2-norm" for="l2-norm">L2-Norm:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" onclick="myFunction()"><br>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeImg()" type="button">
    Visualize Results</button>

<img id="img">
</body>
```

Also, you don't have to put `String(...)` to get the value of a string, just put the variable name

Comment: I removed the ```String(...)``` commands and also all the lines containing ```text``` since I wasn't actually using them and now my button is calling the ```changeImg()``` function once it's clicked but the image is always the same one, regardless of whether I change the slider value or not, it's always taking the initial slider value that I set in the ```slidercontainer```. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: ```document.getElementById("sl").value``` doesn't seem to be outputting the same value as ```this.value```

Comment: Do I need to call ```myFunction()``` ```onclick``` together with ```changeImg()```?

Comment: You don't have to call it together

Comment: Either way, the change in the slider value isn't affecting the image source..